# .htaccess rewrite URI w/ replace part of it

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

Today I have

https://www.teste.com/app/assets/folderX/file.pdf

But I need to redirect to:

https://assets.teste.com/folderX/file.pdf

I got close to the solution with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/app/assets/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://assets.teste.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA,NC]
```

But the rewrite ended like:

https://assets.teste.com/app/assets/folderX/file.pdf

On the ReWrite I need to **remove the subfolder /app/assets/** from it.... but I have no idea how.

---

After some tries. could do it using:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/app/assets/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?app/assets/(.*)$ https://assets.teste.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I nice tool to test is https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this rule instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(teste\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(app)/assets/(.*)$ https://$1.%1/$2 [R=301,L,NE,NC]
```

Make sure to use a new browser to test this change or completely clear old browser cache.

Comment: sorry there was a typo, fixed it now. Please try again.

Comment: fixed the [NC[ to [NC] and worked fine. but I wrote the question wrong. I the end result must be withOUT /app/assets , so would be https://assets.teste.com/folderX/file.pdf

Comment: Worked... But as I asked the wrong question, it´s not what I need.

Comment: Got close doing :
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(teste\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(app)/(assets/.*)$ https://assets.%1/$2 [R=301,L,NE,NC]

but I need to remove /assets/ from url

Comment: Probably you didn't notice change in my answer. `assets/` is already outside the capture groups hence it won't be included in target URL. You need to test in a new browser to avoid old cache or use command line curl to test.

Comment: Sorry, didnt see. Got another work arround. thanks anyway.